# XSLT Remove blank namespaces without assigning elements to different or default namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have the following XML:

```
<ns1:A xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace2.com">
<B>
    <C>123</C>
</B>
<ns2:D>
    <E>456</E>
</ns2:D>
</ns1:A>
```

I want to transform it using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs xsi">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|namespace::*[name()]"/>
        <xsl:if test="text() != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), 'xyz')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output has the undesirable blank namespaces for elements B and E:

```
<A xmlns="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace2.com">
<B xmlns="">
  <C>123xyz</C>
</B>
<D xmlns="http://www.namespace2.com">
  <E xmlns="">456xyz</E>
</D>
</A>
```

My desire is to remove the blank namespaces in the output. I've seen many posts regarding assigning a default namespace, or assigning the elements to some parent namespace.  However that's not what I want.  In the output, I do want elements B,C, and E to remain in the "blank" namespace, because that's what the corresponding XSD requires (and I cannot update the XSD for legacy reasons). So the desired output is:

```
 <A xmlns="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace2.com">
 <B>
   <C>123xyz</C>
 </B>
 <D xmlns="http://www.namespace2.com">
   <E>456xyz</E>
 </D>
</A>
```

How can I get rid of the blank namespaces in the output? I also want to point out that the XSLT will be applied to different input XMLs with different schema structure, so the XSLT must be as generic as possible, without hard coding the element or namespace names.

***EDIT:***

Reviewing answers from M. Kay and M. Hor,  I realize that my previous "desired" output is incorrect. As explained by M. Hor, the default namespaces are inherited as listed in my previous "desired" output, which is not what I want either. (Sorry for the incorrect "desired" output).

My (corrected) desired output is to NOT use any default namespaces, but use namespace prefixes instead:

```
<ns1:A xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace2.com">
   <B>
      <C>123xyz</C>
   </B>
   <ns2:D>
      <E>456xyz</E>
   </ns2:D>
</ns1:A>
```

I've updated my XSLT as an answer to this question below, which outputs what I want.

Thanks!
IK

Answer (score 1):

> (The input and output is the same only because I am using a simplified
>   XSLT for now).

It's difficult to understand the problem when your XSLT is not actually changing anything. For the declared purpose, the [*identity transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) template should work just fine:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

***in response to your edit, showing a different desired output:***

You say that:

> I do want elements B,C, and E to remain in the "blank" namespace

but that is **NOT** what happens in your desired output:

```
<A xmlns="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace1.com"
   xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace2.com">
   <B>
      <C>123xyz</C>
   </B>
   <D xmlns="http://www.namespace2.com">
      <E>456xyz</E>
   </D>
</A>
```

Here, elements `B` and `C` inherit their namespace from their `A` ancestor. Similarly, the `E` element is in the same namespace as its `D` parent.

That's how it works when you declare a *default namespace*: all the elements within the scope of the declaration are placed in that namespace. In order to place `B` in no-namespace, you must make an explicit exception. This is why you see the `<B xmlns="">` in your real result.

Comment: You are right, my original question is a little unclear - I've updated my question to make it more clear.  The identity transform is not what I want because the output will not be identical to the input XML.  The main issue for me is to get rid of the blank namespaces in the output xmlns="" and at the same time keep elements B, C and E to have no namespaces assigned.

Comment: @ILK You could simply add the `xsl:if` and its contents to the identity transform template. Or (more likely in a real-world scenario) add more specific templates to override the identity transform where necessary. But the "*main issue*" that you mention cannot be solved the way you propose - see the edit to my answer to understand why.

Comment: Thank you - Your explanation made me realize that my desired output (with the default namespaces) is not what I want either.  I've edited my question with the corrected desired output.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that the `xmlns=""` declaration is undesirable, presumably what you mean is that you want the B element to be in namespace `http://www.namespace1.com`. So what you need to do is to put it in that namespace. You created the element using the instruction `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">`, so you explicitly put the new B element in the same namespace as the old (that is, in no namespace). If you want to put it in a different namespace, just change this instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I realize that my previous desired output is incorrect. I've updated my question to list the corrected desired output.

Comment: It's probably best to open a new question. Modifying an answer in response to a modified question just gets too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT will output namespace prefixes and not output the default namespaces, thereby avoiding the xmlns="" in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs xsi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|namespace::*[name()]"/>
        <xsl:if test="text() != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), 'xyz')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, instead of using local-name(), I've used name() instead to include the prefixes.

The output is now:

```
<ns1:A xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace2.com">
<B>
  <C>123xyz</C>
</B>
<ns2:D>
  <E>456xyz</E>
</ns2:D>
</ns1:A>
```

Note: This is tested using Saxon Home Edition 9.4. I noticed that other XSLT processors might still output the xmlns="".

Comment: Your first template is redundant: the built-in template rules do this for you. Your second template is basically doing the same thing as the *identity transform* template. IOW, you have gone back to the situation I have dealt with in the first version of my answer.